# Why might both the TELEPHONY_SERVICE and WIFI_SERVICE be unavailable on Android tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, telephonymanager

I have a user with a Sprint Evo View 4G Tablet, and we have a feature that requires either the TELEPHONY_SERVICE or WIFI_SERVICE to be accessible to our app (and we of course request these permissions in our AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Can anyone speculate as to why this device might return null for both of these API calls:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Thanks!

Comment: That seems odd. You're sure they're returning null?

Comment: Well, I don't have it reproing in front of me in a debugger because I do not own the device, but given the code, the only other possibility I see is that WifiManager does return a non-null value but then wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress(); returns null. Clearly if there was no active wifi connection then that would make sense, but in the screen shot supplied by our user, it appears that there is, in fact, an active wifi connection. Hence, I am stumped.

Comment: "the only other possibility I see is that WifiManager does return a non-null value but then wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress(); returns null" -- I'd consider that less crazy. :-) That being said, it doesn't sound good either. Having a connection should not matter -- the MAC address doesn't change. Maybe if WiFi were disabled you wouldn't get a MAC address, but I haven't played around with that.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your thoughts. Anecdotally, this issue seems to only affect Android tablets; we have not heard similar reports from members with Android phones. It seems like it may be an Android OS bug.